# jprogressbar indeterminate mode does not work

Tags: java, jprogressbar

Everyone, I am writing the program which uses jprogressbar.
I do not need to know the exact percentage of how far work is done but just want to let the user know that program is working while it is calculating.

What I want to implement is that as soon as an user click the button called "Analyze", jprogressbar is running in indeterminate mode which is just moving back and forth. I wrote the program as jprogressbar is explained in the example from the oracle but it does not run.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter; 
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;


   @SuppressWarnings( "serial" )
   public class FileDragDemo
   extends JPanel
   {

   private JList list = new JList();

   private JButton btnCompare, btnAnalyze, btnRefresh;

   private JTextField textResultField;

   final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

   File settingFile = null;

   SettingReader readSetting = null;

   public Calculation calculationData = null;

   private JProgressBar progressBar;

   private Task task;

   class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
       /*
        * Main task. Executed in background thread.
        */
       @Override
       public Void doInBackground() {
           Random random = new Random();
           int progress = 0;
           //Initialize progress property.
           setProgress(0);
           while (progress < 100) {
               //Sleep for up to one second.
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
               } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
               //Make random progress.
               progress += random.nextInt(10);
               setProgress(Math.min(progress, 100));
           }
           return null;
       }

       /*
        * Executed in event dispatching thread
        */
       @Override
       public void done() {
           Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();

           setCursor(null); //turn off the wait cursor

       }
   }

   public FileDragDemo()
   {
       setPreferredSize(new Dimension(410, 165));
       progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
       progressBar.setValue(0);
       progressBar.setStringPainted(true); 
       add(progressBar);

       try
       {
           getFile();
           String fileExtension = getFileExtension( settingFile );

           if ( fileExtension.equals( "ini" ) )
           {               
                   readSetting = new SettingReader(settingFile);
            }

           while (fileExtension.equals( "ini" ) == false){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Choose .ini file for configuration" );
               getFile();
               fileExtension = getFileExtension( settingFile );
           }
       }
       catch ( IOException e )
       {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }


       list.setDragEnabled( true );
       list.setTransferHandler( new FileListTransferHandler( list ) );

       JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( list );



       btnCompare = new JButton( "Compare" );
       btnCompare.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
       {
           public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent arg0 )
           {

               progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
               try
               {
                   File file1 = (File) list.getModel().getElementAt( 0 );
                   File file2 = (File) list.getModel().getElementAt( 1 );

                   System.out.println( file1.getPath() );
                   System.out.println( file2.getPath() );

                   try
                   {
                       CompareTwoValues twoValuesToCompare = new CompareTwoValues( file1.getPath(), file2.getPath() );
                       if ( twoValuesToCompare.result() == true )
                       {


                           textResultField.setBackground( Color.green );
                           textResultField.setText( twoValuesToCompare.toString() );
                       }
                       if ( twoValuesToCompare.result() == false )
                       {

                           textResultField.setBackground( Color.RED );
                           textResultField.setText( twoValuesToCompare.toString() );
                       }

                   }
                   catch ( IOException e )
                   {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "File(s) cannot be analyzed or compared" );
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }

               catch ( java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException e )
               {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Please select 2 files to compare" );
                   return;
               }
               catch ( java.lang.NumberFormatException e)
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Wrong Input, choose right file to Compare" );
                   DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
                   listModel.removeAllElements();
                   return;
               }

               progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
               progressBar.setValue(100);

           }
       } );

       btnAnalyze = new JButton( "Analyze" );
       btnAnalyze.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
       {
           public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent arg0 )
           {
               progressBar.setVisible(true);
               progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);


               try
               {
               TrackReader BinaryReader = null;

               File importingFile = (File) list.getModel().getElementAt( 0 );
               String fileExtension = getFileExtension( importingFile );

                   if ( fileExtension.equals( "txt" ) )
                   {
                       try
                       {
                           BinaryReader = new TextTrackReader( importingFile );
                           calculationData = new Calculation(BinaryReader, readSetting, progressBar);
                       }
                       catch ( IOException e1 )
                       {
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Wrong Input, choose right file to Analyze" );
                           e1.printStackTrace();
                           return;
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       if ( fileExtension.equals( "tracks" ) ){
                       try
                       {
                           String BinaryReaderPath1 = importingFile.getAbsolutePath();
                           BinaryReader = new BinaryTrackReader( BinaryReaderPath1 );
                           calculationData = new Calculation(BinaryReader, readSetting, progressBar);
                       }
                       catch ( IOException  |  java.lang.NumberFormatException e)
                       {
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Wrong Input, choose right file to Analyze" );

                           e.printStackTrace();
                           return;
                       }
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Wrong Input, choose right file to Analyze" );
                           return;
                       }
                   }


               progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
               progressBar.setValue(100);
               JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Result" );
               frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
               frame.getContentPane().add( new ResultFrame( calculationData ) );
               frame.pack();
               frame.setVisible( true );
               }

               catch ( java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException e )
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "File cannot be analyzed. Please choose a correct .ini file and data file" );
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   return;
               }
               catch ( IOException e )
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               catch ( java.lang.NumberFormatException e)
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Wrong Input, choose right file to Analyze" );
                   DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
                   listModel.removeAllElements();
                   return;
               }


           }

       } );

       btnRefresh = new JButton( "Refresh" );
       btnRefresh.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
       {
           public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent arg0 )
           {


               try
               {
               btnAnalyze.setEnabled(true);
               btnCompare.setEnabled(true);
               DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
               listModel.removeAllElements();
               }
               catch (  java.lang.ClassCastException e )
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "No list to refresh" );
                   return;
                   // e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }

       } );

       textResultField = new JTextField();
       textResultField.setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.CENTER );
       textResultField.setColumns( 10 );

       progressBar = new JProgressBar();

       // if (listModel.getSize() > 1){
       // btnAnalyze.setEnabled( false );
       // }
       GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout( this );
       groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
           groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
               .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                   .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false)
                       .addComponent(progressBar, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                       .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 316, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                   .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                   .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false)
                       .addComponent(textResultField, 0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                       .addComponent(btnRefresh, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                       .addComponent(btnAnalyze, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                       .addComponent(btnCompare, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                   .addContainerGap(239, Short.MAX_VALUE))
       );
       groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
           groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
               .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                   .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false)
                       .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                           .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 144, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                           .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                           .addComponent(progressBar, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                       .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                           .addContainerGap()
                           .addComponent(btnCompare)
                           .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                           .addComponent(btnAnalyze)
                           .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                           .addComponent(btnRefresh)
                           .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                           .addComponent(textResultField)))
                   .addContainerGap(316, Short.MAX_VALUE))
       );
       setLayout( groupLayout );
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui()
   {
       FileDragDemo mainPanel = new FileDragDemo();

       JFrame frame = new JFrame( "OSCAR" );
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
       frame.getContentPane().add( mainPanel );
       frame.pack();
       frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
       frame.setVisible( true );
       frame.setResizable(false);
   }

   private static String getFileExtension( File file )
   {
       String fileName = file.getName();
       if ( fileName.lastIndexOf( "." ) != -1 && fileName.lastIndexOf( "." ) != 0 )
           return fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf( "." ) + 1 );
       else
           return "";
   }

   public void getFile()
                   throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
                  { 
                      JFileChooser myChooser = new JFileChooser();
                      FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("INI File", "ini");
                      myChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                      int returnVal = myChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                      if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                          settingFile = myChooser.getSelectedFile();
                      }
                      else {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                  }

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
       {
           public void run()
           {
               createAndShowGui();
           }
       } );
   }

   class FileListTransferHandler
       extends TransferHandler
   {

       private JList list;

       public FileListTransferHandler( JList list )
       {
           this.list = list;
       }

       public int getSourceActions( JComponent c )
       {
           return COPY_OR_MOVE;
       }

       public boolean canImport( TransferSupport ts )
       {
           return ts.isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor );
       }

       public boolean importData( TransferSupport ts )
       {
           try
           {
               @SuppressWarnings( "rawtypes" )
               List data = (List) ts.getTransferable().getTransferData( DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor );
               if ( data.size() < 1 )
               {
                   return false;
               }

               DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
               for ( Object item : data )
               {
                   File file = (File) item;
                   listModel.addElement( file );

               }

               list.setModel( listModel );
               if ( list.getModel().getSize() == 2 )
               {
                   btnCompare.setEnabled( true );
                   btnAnalyze.setEnabled( false );
               }
               else if ( list.getModel().getSize() == 1 )
               {
                   btnCompare.setEnabled( false );
                   btnAnalyze.setEnabled( true );
               }
               else if ( list.getModel().getSize() > 2 )
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Choose one or two files" );
                   listModel = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
                   listModel.removeAllElements();
               }
               return true;

           }
           catch ( UnsupportedFlavorException e )
           {
               return false;
           }
           catch ( IOException e )
           {
               return false;
           }
       }

   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? For indeterminate mode of jprogressbar, I do not think I do not even need to run the thread. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What look and feel are you using?

Comment: Hello, Adam. I am not quite sure what your question is but jprogressbar that I am using is just default one.